# Maximum call stack size exceeded at HTMLFormElement.toString using modal Form ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to submit a form using ajax request which is in a modal window.

The modal is opened by clicking this link:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#modal-review" data-toggle="modal">
  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Write a review
</a>
```

the modal window:

```
<div class="modal  fade" id="modal-review" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title-site text-center">PRODUCT REVIEW </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3 class="reviewtitle uppercase">Product: {{ $product->Name }}</h3>
            <form id="review-form" method="post" action="{{ route('add-review') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="review-name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="review-name"  required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="review-email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="review-email"  required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="review-title">Title: (optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="review-title"  required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="review-comment">Review</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="review-comment"  required></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="send-review" class="btn btn-primary">Send review</button>
                <div id="review-response"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when i click the send button i get:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at HTMLFormElement.toString (<anonymous>)
```

What i did wrong or what i forgot to do?

The code for ajax request is:

```
$('#send-review').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#review-form');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'review-name':$('#review-name').val(), 'review-email':$('#review-email').val(), 'review-title':$('#review-title').val(), 'review-comment':$('#review-comment')},
        success: function (response) {
            if(!response.error){
                console.log(response.msg);                   
            } else {
                console.log(response.msg);                    
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the function does not recursively call itself in a way or another? Can you reproduce it in a snippet based on the code you've posted? If you can't, there is likely another interfering method that causes runaway recursive form submission. Also, you should really be listening on the form's `submit` event, i.e. `$('#review-form').on('submit'...)` instead of the button click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
....'review-comment':$('#review-comment')},
```

Change that to:

```
.....'review-comment': $('#review-comment').val()
```

```js
$('#send-review').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $('#review-form');
  $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          'review-name': $('#review-name').val(),
          'review-email': $('#review-email').val(),
          'review-title': $('#review-title').val(),
          'review-comment': $('#review-comment').val()
      },
      success: function (response) {
          if (!response.error) {
              console.log(response.msg);
          } else {
              console.log(response.msg);
          }
      },
      error: function(response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#modal-review').modal('hide');
            console.log(response);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#modal-review" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Write a review
</a>

<div class="modal  fade" id="modal-review" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title-site text-center">PRODUCT REVIEW </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3 class="reviewtitle uppercase">Product: {{ $product->Name }}</h3>

                <form id="review-form" method="post" action="{{ route('add-review') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="review-name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="review-name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="review-email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="review-email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="review-title">Title: (optional)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="review-title" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="review-comment">Review</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="review-comment" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="send-review" class="btn btn-primary">Send review</button>
                    <div id="review-response"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using names in form and the old form.serialize() works!

```
 $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',            
        data: form.serialize(),            
        success: function (response) {
            if(!response.error){
                console.log(response.msg);                    
            } else {
                console.log(response.msg);                    
            }
        }
    });
```