# Set HTML tag as a value of an object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have HTML tags that I want to display as HTML(not string) within an object,
the problem is when I display it ,it's still as text not as HTML

```
var obj = {  "CategoryItemID": "ID",
             "ItemName": "name",
             "options":"<a title='Edit' ng-click='edit()' id='btnEdit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> |" +
                        "<a title='Delete' ng-click='delete()' " +
                        "id='btnDelete'><span style='color:red' class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>",
                           "children": "",
          }
```

How can I read from object as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DOM Parser You can here is the example

```js
 var obj = {  "CategoryItemID": "ID",
                           "ItemName": "name",
                           "options":"<a title='Edit' ng-click='edit()' id='btnEdit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> |" +
                        "<a title='Delete' ng-click='delete()' " +
                        "id='btnDelete'><span style='color:red' class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>",
                           "children": "",
                       }
                       
var parser = new DOMParser()
var node = parser.parseFromString(obj.options, "text/html");
console.log(node.body.innerHTML)
```

Whatever you want to access you can access like as follows

```
node.body.getElementsByTagName("a")
node.body.getElementsByClassName("something")
```

Try this to show that in table

```js
  var obj = {  "CategoryItemID": "ID",
                               "ItemName": "name",
                               "options":"<a title='Edit' ng-click='edit()' id='btnEdit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span></a> |" +
                            "<a title='Delete' ng-click='delete()' " +
                            "id='btnDelete'><span style='color:red' class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>",
                               "children": "",
                           }
                           
    var parser = new DOMParser()
    var node = parser.parseFromString(obj.options, "text/html");
document.getElementsByClassName("option")[0].innerHTML=node.body.innerHTML;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.0/css/all.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Option</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sourabh</td>
    <td class="option"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I got this error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at DOMStringMap.toString (<anonymous>)

Comment: Are you accessing like `node.body`

Comment: yes now it's work, but still give me the HTML as a text

Comment: What do you want to access

Comment: access like a node.body.getElementsByTagName("a")

Comment: yes that's I want to access but when I print it in td in a table it's appear as text not HTML

Comment: Okay Now I modify my answer again

Comment: you give me the HTML tags as a text and print it in a console , but I want to set it in div or td or any HTML tag

Comment: See my above example now

Comment: @RawanMansour Welcome (y)  :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy DOM element and add the HTML string to it. Then, you can manipulate it like any DOM element.

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = obj.options;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const stringContainingHTMLSource = obj.options;
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingHTMLSource, "text/html");
```

[Parsing an SVG or HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_an_SVG_or_HTML_document)

Comment: I got this error :Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at DOMStringMap.toString (<anonymous>)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801839/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-at-htmlformelement-tostring-using-modal-form-aj might help

Answer (score 0):

Assign the object property to the innerHTML of the corresponding element you want to display.

HTML

```
<div id="displayObject">
</div>
```

JS

```
var displayObj = document.getElementById('displayObject');
displayObj.innerHTML = obj.options;
```

Comment: I am build the html dynamicaly so I can't put the span as that

Comment: Use @DEVCNN approach then